# extjs 6 change the default color text in all the application

Tags: css, extjs, sass, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I want to change the color text in all the application. It is gray and I want to change it in black. I am using classic.
in CSS, I found this:

```
.x-body {
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

when I uncheck '-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;' I get the black.
Please how to change it? and of course if you have other alternatives thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the architecture of your application, if you are using one of ext's sass themes and overriding them, you can do the following: search for **$color** sass variable in ext's documentation, it will present a list of global_css variables that are intended to be overridden. All of these are coming from Component.scss file. Than you can give different values to variables coming from component.scss and use it the way it suits your needs.